# IIS Remove Subdirectory from urls - web.config & .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

I've asked question before but haven't found solution. So I'm posting again with some additional infos. I've tried to move all file to root from sub-directory called (Silverstripe), but then blank page showed up. even i delete **default.aspx** and **web.config** file too. and also played with **.htaccess** file. and I'm not much awar of these stuff, so this is why i posted my issue here.

The Problem is I want to remove sub-directory from url & permalinks as well. e.g.

http://www.jtrainingsolutions.com/Silverstripe/ **=>** http://www.jtrainingsolutions.com/

**Root Map:**

```
 - /Silverstripe - (Subdirectory)
     - root/Silverstripe/.htaccess
     - root/Silverstripe/web.config
     - root/and other Silverstripe CMS files
 - /default.aspx
```

**default.aspx:**

```
<%
If InStr( UCase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")),  UCase("www.jtrainingsolutions.com") ) > 0 Then  
        Response.Redirect("/Silverstripe")  
ElseIf InStr( UCase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")), UCase("jtrainingsolutions.com") ) > 0 Then  
        Response.Redirect("/Silverstripe")  
End If  
%>
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 /silverstripe-cache(/|$)
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif$)|(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.css$)|(\.js$)|(\.php$)

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Silverstripe/$1 [L]

    RewriteBase /Silverstripe
</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

and **web.config file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="false">
                    <add segment="silverstripe-cache" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SilverStripe Clean URLs" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="sapphire/main.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please advise me how to fix this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: please help me about this matter. I really stuck here...